# Connect sensor or LED to HM-10 Bluetooth Module

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

Can I connect a sensor or a LED to HM-10 Bluetooth Module without Arduino?
If yes, how to upload a code to it ( not an AT commands)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HM-10 at most cases can't work as standalone device, It needs an Arduino or microcontroller and they can do the hard work(processing and doing commands) while HM-10 is the gateway for them to communicate with other devices using Bluetooth.